# Want to change up and down arrow style into left and right arrow style in NumericStepper in flex 3

Tags: flex3

Want to change up and down arrow style into left and right arrow style in NumericStepper in flex 3

Answer (score 0):

I think the styles you are looking for are these:

```
upArrowDisabledSkin="NumericStepperUpSkin"
upArrowDownSkin="NumericStepperUpSkin"
upArrowOverSkin="NumericStepperUpSkin"
upArrowUpSkin="NumericStepperUpSkin"
```

Taken from Adobe Livedocs for a NumericStepper. They're skins, so I think you'll essentially be using images.

Comment: I want to convert it into horizontal format something like <- [] ->

Comment: I fear you may have to create your own component to do this then... I don't think it should be too difficult, simply two buttons and a textbox in the middle.